# Icinga Agent Security

Tags: linux, monitoring, icinga

i have tried to search this on internet , but coudn't find a answer.

I have setup Icinga2 on my LAN network, and a remote client on a cloud VPS(using the icinga default distributed monitoring with zones).

My Icinga has access to VPS port 5665;
VPS can't reach my icinga (firewalled LAN)

My Icinga can run commands on VPS and its working perfectly.
In my old Nagios setup, using NRPE i used to setup a password so a rogue server couldn't exploit my open 5666 port.

How Icinga secures this since it has no password?

Answer (score 2):

In short: SSL certificates

Longer: It's all in the docs

- [Note about ApiListener in Distributed Monitoring](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/06-distributed-monitoring/#apilistener)
- [ApiListener Configuration](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/09-object-types/#objecttype-apilistener)
- Same Listener is used for the [Icinga 2 API](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/12-icinga2-api/)